# How to optimally decide modified square wave duty cycle for an inverter?

Tags: voltage, inverter, square, duty-cycle

Some high-end inverters synthesize a sine wave with high speed pulse width modulation and low-pass filtering, but most cheaper inverters use a square wave or a modified square wave.

Modified square wave is defined as:

- From T = `0` .. `1/f*0.5*dutycycle`: V<sub>peak</sub>
- From T = `1/f*0.5*dutycycle` .. `1/f*0.5`: 0 V
- From T = `1/f*0.5` .. `1/f*0.5 + 1/f*0.5*dutycycle`: -V<sub>peak</sub>
- From T = `1/f*0.5 + 1/f*0.5*dutycycle` .. `1/f`: 0 V

If `dutycycle = 1` then this gives a standard square wave with no time spent at zero volts.

How should the duty cycle be optimally decided for a modified square wave so that most devices work as well as they can?

Answer (score 4):

There are several considerations that govern the determination of an optimal duty cycle.

Firstly, so that resistive loads work with no modification in power, the RMS voltage of the modified square wave should be the line voltage, for example 230 volts.

We can determine that this gives V<sub>peak</sub> of `230 V / sqrt(dutycycle)` as the value of V<sub>peak</sub> that does not modify power of resistive loads by maintaining 230 volt RMS voltage.

A second common kind of load is a load that depends on the peak voltage of the waveform. Simple power supplies that have a transformer, full wave rectifier bridge and a capacitor depend on the peak voltage. Also microwave ovens that are of the conventional type (not of the inverter type) are heavily dependent on the peak voltage. Furthermore, a switched mode power supply with no power factor correction has a full wave rectifier bridge, a capacitor and the switch mode circuitry after that and thus is dependent on the peak voltage of the waveform. Today most switched mode power supplies however have an active power factor correction circuit that works like a boost converter that pulls power from the input not only at the peak voltage but during the entire time the waveform is non-zero.

In sine wave, the peak voltage is `230 V * sqrt(2)`, so to maintain the peak voltage, we should have `1/sqrt(dutycycle) = sqrt(2)` or `dutycycle = 0.5`.

Unfortunately, a modified square wave that has 50% duty cycle has terrible harmonic distortion. Using Fourier analysis, we obtain that 48.4% of the energy is not on the base frequency but at higher frequencies. This could cause motors to buzz far louder than a wave that would have lower harmonic distortion.

Another approach that is possible is to use the duty cycle that gives lowest possible harmonic distortion. The value is about `dutycycle = 0.742` and the corresponding harmonic distortion is 29.0%.

Unfortunately, at this duty cycle the peak voltage is only 267 volts. Devices working on 230 volts are supposed to withstand 10% smaller and 10% larger voltage, so the permissible RMS voltage range is 207 V .. 253 V, and the permissible peak voltage range is 292.74 V .. 357.80 V. The peak voltage of 267 volts that optimizes harmonic distortion is not in this permissible range. Hence, devices that depend on the peak voltage might not work.

A third approach is not to optimize peak voltage or harmonic distortion, but rather select a peak voltage that is barely in the permissible range of 292.74 V .. 357.8 V (so in other words, pick V<sub>peak</sub> of 292.74 V). The lower the peak voltage (and the higher the duty cycle), in this range, the lower the harmonic distortion is.

V<sub>rms</sub> of 230 V and V<sub>peak</sub> of 292.74 V gives `230 V / sqrt(dutycycle) = 292.74 V` or `dutycycle = 0.617`.

A duty cycle of 0.617 gives harmonic distortion of 34.6%. It's slightly worse than the optimal harmonic distortion of 29.0% but not much worse. More importantly, with a duty cycle of 0.617 the peak voltage of the waveform is still in the permissible range, so devices depending on the peak voltage should work.

An inverter I recently bought (300W 24V -> 230V) seems to use this approach of "use 230 volts for RMS voltage, use lowest possible peak voltage still within the spec to optimize duty cycle for harmonic distortion".

It's possible also to use both higher V<sub>rms</sub> than 230 volts and also lower V<sub>peak</sub> than 325.27 volts. For example, using the highest permitted V<sub>rms</sub> of 253 volts and the lowest permitted V<sub>peak</sub> of 292.74 volts, we can obtain a duty cycle of at most 0.747, which is about that of the duty cycle of lowest possible harmonic distortion. However, modifying the V<sub>rms</sub> by increasing it 10% makes incandescent light bulbs burn very bright and burn out very quickly, and resistive loads would create 21% more heat than they're supposed to create. It's probably not a good tradeoff to make incandescent light bulbs burn very quickly and to create 21% more heat in resistive heating elements if the only benefit that is achieved is reduction of harmonic distortion from 34.6% (motors will buzz) to 29.0% (motors will buzz but only very slightly less than with 34.6%).

(Edit: I forgot to take square root in harmonic distortion in the first version of the answer so the harmonic distortion figures were off, fixed now.)